# Use a form instead of content type in maestro drupal module

Tags: 7, nodes

I am working on `maestro module` of `Drupal 7`, the module uses `content type` to add the form fields ,but instead of `content type` i want to use simple form which i have created using `php` , can anyone please help me , it is very urgent.
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

**for those who are  still searching the answer for this question**

We can use `webform` instead of `content type` with `maestro`, for that we need `maestro_webform_task` module, the module will integrates 
both web form and `maestro` and provides the list of already created web forms in `web form` `task->edit->select web form to use`

[maestro_webform_task](https://www.drupal.org/project/maestro_webform_task)